# Set the session cookie for elasticsearch

Tags: java, curl, cookies

I have the following code which gets the session id and I am setting it in the request property for the next connections.

```java
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
List<String> cookies = con.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
for (String cookie : cookies) {
    logger.info("SESSION COOKIE :" +cookie);
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 2)[0]);
    con.connect();
}
```

But when I make the requests through curl to port 9200, like this:

`curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer hgwuyegyud263462" https://localhost:9200`

I have to set the new bearer token. Is it because I am not using browser that saves the session? Or what do I have to do to not enter the bearer token every time?